# Why is this cron entry executed twice?

Tags: cron

```
*/5 * * * * my command
```

This entry works but every 5 minutes it gets executed twice, why?

In `/var/log/cron` it shows:

```
Jun 16 22:20:01 Test CROND[12512]: (root) CMD (my command)
Jun 16 22:20:01 Test CROND[12516]: (root) CMD (my command)
```

So it's not from two users.

It is only entered once with `crontab -e -u root`. The command is a php command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why my cron job executing multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012666/why-my-cron-job-executing-multiple-times)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Nothing in the description gives reason for it to be executed twice. Look elsewhere.

- Do two users call it?
- Is it entered twice?
- Does it call itself?
- Does it set in motion conditions for repetition?

If it's a shell script you're executing, have it append `whoami` and `date` to a log file. You should be able to dig up the reason.

## UPDATE

Type `ps -A | grep crond`, make sure crond isn't running twice.

Comment: you didn't answer: does it call itself? does it set in motion conditions for repetition?

Comment: This was the solution to my problem, cron was running more than once.  On my system, I had to look for cron, not crond.  Once I stopped and started the cron service, it only had one running instance.  Thanks @StefanMai

Comment: Another Question you could ask: "Do you simply log it twice in syslog config?"

Comment: ps -A may be confusing since cron will create children that will be listed on separate lines. 'ps axjf' will list a tree with 'cron' at the root for the main cron process; easier to spot if there are more than one roots.

Comment: Upvote for 'ps axjf' - thank you. Every day's a school day.

Comment: A quick one to add to the accepted answer - have you somehow duplicated your crontab? I'm using ElasticBeanstalk to deploy my application I just noticed I have a `/etc/cron.d/certbot_renew` AND a `/etc/cron.d/certbot_renew.bak`.  For [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files): If the file path you specify already exists on the instance, the existing file is retained with the extension .bak appended to its name.

Answer (score 11):

The wget in crontab has often a limit of 15 minutes. In our case this was just the case, and after those 15 minutes the job ends up with a timeout and then re-runs again right away. So, the solution to this was to set up the cronjob in crontab somewhat like this :

```
1 2 * * * root wget --read-timeout=3600 -O - 'http://cron-job-url' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

...instead of

```
 1 2 * * * root wget -O - 'http://cron-job-url' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So, wget is the thing. Meaning 3600 = 1 hour then. Or more if you need!

Comment: What happen if if I run the cron every minute (* * * * *) ?  What value should I set for --read-timeout?

Comment: --read-timeout=60 then, I guess? :) Added with the thought that a job that runs every minute maybe shouldn't be too big of a job!

Comment: This saved me from countless hour of searching ghosts

Answer (score 3):

For sure it's not the crontab entry that's causing it to run twice.  The fastest way to find out what is going on is to add some debugging to the cron job script.  If you do nothing, then by default the cron output will be mailed to `root@localhost` (unless you have configured this to be different), so assuming you have root access, add some debugging information to the script, such as:

```
echo "Script starting"
date
whoami
```

and look at the output.  This will get you started as to figuring out how this is getting called twice.

Comment: This helped me to detect other crontab user. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If it's a command for an application you installed, maybe it already added the same entry to `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/cron.d/<something>`.

Comment: This was my problem - I had manually entered it into the root crontab, but there was also a file in `/etc/cron.d` calling a very similar but not exactly the same version of the same call.  Tail-chasing now finished, back to the job at hand. :)

Answer (score 3):

I do confirm - my cron also run twice...

```
Jul 24 14:40:01 localhost cron[2713]: (root) CMD (/etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do)
Jul 24 14:41:01 localhost cron[9481]: (root) CMD (/etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do)
Jul 24 14:41:01 localhost cron[10724]: (root) CMD (/etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do)
Jul 24 14:42:01 localhost cron[20380]: (root) CMD (/etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do)
Jul 24 14:42:01 localhost cron[20832]: (root) CMD (/etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do)
```

My crontab

grep -R /var/spool/ -e reloader

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root:* * * * * /etc/apache2/generator/reloader.do
```

output of:

```
whoami
date
------
```

output:

```
root
root
Tue Jul 24 14:46:02 CEST 2012
---------
Tue Jul 24 14:46:03 CEST 2012
---------
```

My current workaround is:

```
if [ -f /etc/apache2/generator/reloader.lock ]
then
exit
fi
touch /etc/apache2/generator/reloader.lock
/etc/apache2/generator/reloader
rm /etc/apache2/generator/reloader.lock
```

But it's not the answer why that's happen...

System - gentoo
Cron - vixie-cron

part of `ps aux wwf` output (lunched inside cron task)

```
root     10843  0.0  0.0  16480   560 ?        Ss   Jun06   0:01 /usr/sbin/cron
root     29797  0.0  0.0  25020   964 ?        S    15:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/cron
root     29799  0.0  0.0   9188  1228 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00      \_ /bin/bash /etc/apache2/generator/reloader
root     29822  0.0  0.0  14800   988 ?        R    15:08   0:00          \_ ps aux wwf
------
root      8215  0.0  0.0  16480   836 ?        Ss   14:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root     31419  0.0  0.0  25020   968 ?        S    15:08   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/cron
root     31423  0.0  0.0   9188  1228 ?        Ss   15:08   0:00      \_ /bin/bash /etc/apache2/generator/reloader
root     31431  0.0  0.0  14804  1004 ?        R    15:08   0:00          \_ ps aux wwf
```

EDIT:

I did notice, that one of cron process report Jun06 as start date (today is Jun24)

```
root     10843  0.0  0.0  16480   560 ?        Ss   Jun06   0:01 /usr/sbin/cron
root      8215  0.0  0.0  16480   836 ?        Ss   14:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
```

Second process report correctly (server uprime is ~40 minutes - i did restart it recenty)
One important info - it is V-server running on host machine.

No matter what I do (/etc/init.d/vixie-cron restart) it start's with the same PID

SOLVED:

I've found the reason.
One V-server was run twice, with different context.
Possible explanation - someone has changed the context while machine was running, and as a result, not all processes were killed, and what;s more - they did affect new instance of vserver (context 303 and 3031):

```
root     10843  3031 developer      0.0  0.0  16480   560 ?        Ss   Jun06   0:01 /usr/sbin/cron
root     16509   303 developer      0.0  0.0  16480   836 ?        Ss   15:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
```

I've TERM old process, and problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

I *thought* cron was launching my bash script twice, but I was wrong. I thought I'd share my experience for (hopefully) the benefit of others.  It had me scratching my head for a bit ...

At the moment of being launched by cron, 'ps aux' output changed from showing 0 instances of my script running to two instances, or so it seems at first blush:

```
kdeen    1797750  0.0  0.0   2608   600 ?        Ss   15:52   0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/kdeen/bin/once-a-day-local.sh
kdeen    1797751  0.0  0.0  19520  3488 ?        S    15:52   0:00 /bin/bash /home/kdeen/bin/once-a-day-local.sh
```

But look a little closer and I see one instance is /bin/sh -c and the other is /bin/bash.  This is correct behavior.  My script starts with "#!/bin/bash" but cron ALWAYS runs stuff with /bin/sh.  So there's an 'sh' launcher process and then there's my bash script.  All good.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, in my case was that I initialize the cron service twice by mistake. After I stopped cron `# /etc/init.d/crond stop` and started it again `# /etc/init.d/crond start`, it worked perfectly.

I hope this can help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who got this far without a solution, don't make the newbie mistake (like I did!) of starting your crontab with `* 05 * * 0` and expecting it to run once on a Sunday.

In fact, it will try to run every minute after 5 a.m. (until in my case it crashed the Postgres backup). You need to specify a minute as ell, if you only want it to run once:

`0 05 * * 0`

Answer (score 1):

## In my case a prepended `sleep` caused confusion.

Actually not the `sleep` itself, but rather **the linking and operator (`&&`) produced an anonymous parent process with the actual script as a sub process**. This was not evident because `sleep` had finished, the script had started, and `grep` hid the child-parent relationship.

### Check for the following:

```bash
sudo ps aux wwf

# -> are the 2 process child and parent?
# example output (first cols cut off for readability):
#
#    /usr/sbin/cron -f
#    \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
#        \_ /bin/bash -c sleep 5m && /path/some_script.sh
#            \_ /path/some_script.sh
```

### For reference:

If you had checked earlier (during the `sleep` period) the output would have shown:

```bash
sudo ps aux wwf

#   /usr/sbin/cron -f
#   \_ /usr/sbin/CRON -f
#   \_ /bin/bash -c sleep 5m && /path/some_script.sh
#   \_ sleep 5m
```

Comment: That was also my case, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem due to a double entry in conf file:

```
# grep /syslog /etc/rsyslog.conf /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf 
/etc/rsyslog.conf:*.*;auth,authpriv,kern,mail.none      -/var/log/syslog
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf:*.*;auth,authpriv,kern,mail.none -/var/log/syslog
```

Clearly commenting one of the 2 solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Running ps -A | grep cron, killing all jobs didnt't help in my case.
Problem was after killing all cron jobs and starting again with only one cron daemon I would get two cron jobs started from the same parent cron PPID - one with /bin/bash - the other one with /bin/sh

Solution was to reboot server.

This happened on several occasions, different OSs - centos 6 and redhat 7.
Usually after online OS upgrade without reboot.

As someone said - probably some different context.

I saw one article on the net with same processes one with /bin/bash other one with /bin/sh at exactly same time - i thought yeeee - this is my case - but no, guy didn't even give a thought what is the root cause for such strange behavior, just started writing some script logic to make second process exit which is not really a solution.

BTW ps -A | grep cron will also list all cron childs - normal cron jobs, more cron processes doesn't mean it is more cron daemons, might be only one daemon and others are childs.

ps -ef | grep cron on the other hand lists only one - why?
Because ps -ef lists childs as CROND - to get them all do ps -ef | grep -i cron

Answer (score 0):

I've recently migrated from vixie-cron to cronie and noticed my root crontab was a duplicate of my user crontab file.

Execute/run `crontab -e`, both as a user and as root, and examine the files to ensure duplicate commands are not being issued.

As root:

```
# crontab -e
```

As user:

```
$ crontab -e
```

If the files are significantly similar, might be best to insert a `# TEST` comment within the unwanted crontab contents to insure no symlinks or other anomalies exist prior to deleting the contents of the crontab file.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have two crond's running, one with PID 12512 and one with PID 12516.