# why my cron job executing multiple times?

Tags: shell, cron

I have set up a cron job that need to be executed once a day but it is getting executed multiple times.I have set up it as I mentioned below:

```
5 8 * * * /sh_file_path
```

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening and what should I do to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you add another job will that also be executed multiple times? Say add `5 * * * * date >> /tmp/log.date`. That should get executed once per hour.

Comment: @fredrik all jobs are executing multiple times :(

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8):

Without more knowledge about your particular setup/system, and the fact that all jobs get executed multiple times, I can only surmise that you have multiple cron daemons running on your system.

Do a full process list and grep for `cron` (most of them have that word in the name of the binary) and see how many are running. On a standard linux system, this should work:

```
ps aux | grep cron
```

Then you would have to figure out which should be running and kill the others.

Comment: I can kill for today,what if cron is executing multiple time on daily basis

Comment: If you kill the process it might stay dead until system restart. The bigger question is, why does your system have two cron daemons? It's one of those processes of which "there should be only one". Sort of like udev... Having more can, as you've seen, lead to undesired and/or unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: The only reason for two cron daemons running at the same time is because you or someone else installed and/or started them.

Comment: I got this


root     17115  0.0  0.3  31748  3236 ?        Ss   12:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
ubuntu   17320  0.0  0.1  14856  1024 pts/0    S+   12:36   0:00 grep --color=auto cron

What does this means can you please explain? @fredrik