# Cronjob running twice

Tags: cron, synology

All of my cronjobs seem to be running multiple times per day on my Synology NAS. I am not sure what is going on. I have already found [this solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012666/why-my-cron-job-executing-multiple-times) but I am not sure how to fix the problem. I want to have crond log to a certain file so I have run `crond -L /var/log/cron.log`

In my Cron logs, they seem to only be running once but in my script outputs, they seem to be running multiple times (twice).

Here is the output of `ps | grep cron`

```
20726 root      3816 S    /usr/sbin/crond
21937 root      3816 S    crond -L /var/log/cron.log
28497 root      3768 S    grep cron
```

Is have `/usr/sbin/crond` and my custom `crond` command the reason this is happening? How would I only have one instance of crond but also have it log to a specific file?

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004764/why-is-this-cron-entry-executed-twice

Comment: also try stopping the service with "service cron stop" then check with "service cron status". It should not say running, finally start it with "service cron start". This should rule out if you have multiple "cron" daemons running.

Comment: You would need to modify the startup options for the existing crond to log rather than run your own copy. From the looks of it you should be able to trace where that is in `/usr/syno/etc/rc.d/S04crond.sh`

Comment: I stopped crond service and both crons went away in my ps output.