# Cronjob running more frequently than expected

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have a cron job that is set to run at 1:30am every morning

```
# Run at 1:30am every morning
30 1 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://167.99.XXX.XXX/cron-script-here >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And yet when I look in the apache access log, it's running roughly every 15 minutes. However **it is being called by the server IP** - which is expected as the server is running wget on itself.

```
167.99.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jan/2019:02:00:04 +1300] "GET /cron-script-here HTTP/1.1" 200 945 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)"
167.99.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jan/2019:02:15:08 +1300] "GET /cron-script-here HTTP/1.1" 200 951 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)"
167.99.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jan/2019:02:30:12 +1300] "GET /cron-script-here HTTP/1.1" 200 941 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)"
167.99.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jan/2019:02:45:17 +1300] "GET /cron-script-here HTTP/1.1" 200 947 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)"
167.99.XXX.XXX - - [29/Jan/2019:03:00:23 +1300] "GET /cron-script-here HTTP/1.1" 200 943 "-" "Wget/1.19.4 (linux-gnu)"
...etc...
```

As it's a very straightforward crontab entry, I'm actually not sure where to look next in terms of debugging.

It seemed to only be doing this for a period of a few hours in the middle of the night. I've commented the crontab line out for the time being.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is cron running multiple times? Did you check with `ps -A cron[d]`? See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004764/why-is-this-cron-entry-executed-twice).

Comment: The wget timeout answer there seems to be relevant, too, seeing how the jobs seems to run every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. The cron daemon is only running once. I'll check the wget timeout option now.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm trying bumping up the wget timeout limit. Even if wget was timing out, the scripts themselves completed. I guess this would make sense. This is looking likely. If you want to put that as an answer, once these have run overnight if that solves it I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It was the wget timeout thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Your question isn't an exact duplicate, but if I flag it to close as one, seeing that the answer to another question exactly covered your case, would you accept it as a duplicate? I don't really want to post the answer, I just looked it up on another question.

Comment: If I had've easily found the answer in another question I wouldn't have opened a question, so it could be valuable to highlight the wget timeout specifically - but totally fine if you think it's a duplicate. No issues there.

Comment: If you update your question to be more specifically about wget (by, for example, mentioning it in the title), I'll add a community wiki answer, how does that sound?