# Cronjob wget triggers http requests multiple times in unpredictable intervals

Tags: php, apache, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I setup the crons in ubuntu server for php services using wget and I run crons on every 5 min. It was worked good for some days. Recently, I got an issue that service is running twice or thrice (as per output of application logs) but cron ran for only one time (as per syslog).

I have gone through with link [Why is this cron entry executed twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004764/why-is-this-cron-entry-executed-twice) but it didn't work for me. I have only one PID (ps -aux | grep 'cron') and I restarted,stopped,started the cron service (service cron restart/stop/start) but none of them worked for me. So finally I restarted the server as cron job is init service but after restarting also, I got same issue.

Cron running as root user.

Cron:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate  https://**********/controlller/method
```

From Syslog:

```
Jul 31 12:05:01 web-server CRON[26997]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate  https://xx.xx.xx.xx/controller/method)
Jul 31 12:10:01 web-server CRON[27222]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate  https://xx.xx.xx.xx/controller/method)
Jul 31 12:15:01 web-server CRON[27470]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate  https://xx.xx.xx.xx/controller/method)
Jul 31 12:20:01 web-server CRON[27768]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/wget --no-check-certificate  https://xx.xx.xx.xx/controller/method)

ps -aux | grep 'cron'
root      1079  0.0  0.0  26012   696 ?        Ss   Jul30   0:03 cron
```

From Application logs:

```
31 Jul 2019 12:05:01 [26836] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
31 Jul 2019 12:05:01 [26922] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
31 Jul 2019 12:13:00 [27378] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
31 Jul 2019 12:13:01 [27376] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
31 Jul 2019 12:23:47 [27733] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
31 Jul 2019 12:23:47 [27674] DEBUG [xx.xx.xx.xx]:entered into controller/method
```

From Apache2 access logs:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:05:01 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6914 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:05:01 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6909 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:13:01 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6862 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:13:00 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6862 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:23:47 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6862 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Jul/2019:12:23:47 +0200] "GET /controller/method HTTP/1.1" 200 6862 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
```

Comment: Maybe this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004764/why-is-this-cron-entry-executed-twice

Comment: @hrench i tried that link, i metioned that link in above question