# Docker alpine linux cron jobs running 3 times every time

Tags: linux, azure, docker, cron, alpine-linux

I'm running crontab-ui and php inside a docker container deployed to azure. Every cron job I set up it runs 3 times (email sent 3 times, logged 3 times). Tried a different approach on another container and got the same result.

Here is my crontab:

```
*       *       *       *       *       sh /usr/local/bin/triage-rotate.sh
*       *       *       *       *       sh /usr/local/bin/wp-cron.sh
```

and here is wp-cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
ps -ef | grep "wp cron" | grep -v grep
process=`ps -ef | grep "wp cron" | grep -v grep | wc -l`
echo $process
if [ $process -eq 0 ]; then 
    wp cron event run --due-now --path=/var/www/html/ --allow-root
fi
```

I was watching `top` on terminal and wp-cron.sh only gets triggered once. I have a wp scheduled event that sends an email twicedaily and I receive 3 emails every time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "...a docker container deployed to azure": App Service? Container Instances? Container Apps? Functions? AKS?

Comment: It is an app service for containers running the image from a container registry.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be possible that your hook might be being executed more than once, you can prevent execution of hook more than once on your specific code using **`did_action.`**

- Ensure you should set WordPress Cron to "NO if you are utilizing the cron ***job URL*** to initiate sending. Otherwise, if multiple people attempt to send at the same time, multiple email will be triggered at the end
- Check whether you accidentally initialized the cron service at twice and try to stop cron `# /etc/init.d/crond`  and start it again `# /etc/init.d/crond start,`
- please check whether your system have two cron daemon. The fact that two cron daemons are operating simultaneously due to which these issues may occur. Also, check another user installed and/or activated or needs to be active at once.

Please check this similar [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004764/why-is-this-cron-entry-executed-twice) by *erotsppa*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did check all that prior to asking. There is only one cron daemon running. This is happening in 2 different docker containers deployed to azure web apps, regardless of wordpress instalation. It must be somthing to do with azure docker environment !? Also, inside /etc/crontabs there is only the `root` file.

````24 root      0:04 crond -l 2 -f -c /etc/crontabs````